# Download a PDF file with ruby-on-rails, error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I followed the steps setting a link to download a PDF file on a preview question about that.
Problem is, when I click on the download button, it open a window to show the PDF, but the PDF doesn't show up...
When I open or download it, I got this message "File type unknown (application/octet-stream) is not supported"

What's wrong?
Thank you

Here, how i set it up:

## Controller

```
class HomesController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def download_pdf
    send_file(
        "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/docs/dossier_de_presentation_lvsl.pdf",
        type: "application/pdf"
        x_sendfile: true
        )  
  end
end
```

## routes.rb

```rb
get 'download_pdf', to: "homes#download_pdf"
```

## view

```
<%= link_to "Download Pdf", "/assets/dossier_de_presentation_lvsl.pdf", :class => "themed_text", class: "btn btn-lg btn-custom" %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your controller action is not used at all. Browser tries to download file from the following path `public/assets/dossier_de_presentation_lvsl.pdf`.

If you want to download it through the controller action. You should set your application in following way:

In your routes:

```rb
get '/download_pdf', to: 'homes#download_pdf', as: 'download_pdf'
```

In your controller:

```rb
  def index
  end

  def download_pdf
    send_file(
        "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/docs/dossier_de_presentation_lvsl.pdf",
        type: "application/pdf",
        disposition: 'attachment', # 'inline' if you want to show PDF in the browser instead of downloading it directly
        x_sendfile: true
        )  
  end
end
```

In your view:

```
<%= link_to "Download Pdf", download_pdf_path(format: :pdf), :class => "themed_text", class: "btn btn-lg btn-custom" %>
```

---

Or if you want, you can put your PDF directly to `public` folder in your rails app eg. to `public/pdf/dossier_de_presentation_lvsl.pdf`

and than you can use just a link:

```html
<a href="/pdf/dossier_de_presentation_lvsl.pdf" class="themed_text btn btn-lg btn-custom">Download PDF</a>
```

But you can use this only if your PDF can be downloaded by everyone without any authentication etc. On the other hand you would not have to bother with the controller action and routes, it will be handled for you automatically.